# Using byte as the primary key datatype

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code-first. I have a table the will not exceed 100 rows and I would like to use the datatype `byte` (`tinyint` in SQL Server) as the primary key.

This is what I have so far:

```
[Key]
public byte Id { get; set; }
```

The issue is when Entity Framework creates the database, it is not setting the identity specification property that allows the rows to auto increment on insert.

If I change the datatype to `Int16` (`smallint` in SQL Server) everything works perfectly.

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework to set the auto increment property or can a byte not be used as the primary key with Entity Framework code-first?

Comment: Why would you restrict your database like this? If it's only few rows, the added space does not hurt.

Comment: @delnan, yeah right, why not make it a varchar(100) **`;-)`**.  You should always pick the correct most restrictive data-type available, especially for a PK. If you use this PK as a FK in a table with 50 million rows and add an index on it, there will be a difference. Column size affects more than disk space, just think about cache memory and how much you waste for a trivial data-type selection error.  Also, if your application freaks out and tries to insert an out or range value, it will fail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `byte` type is supported as key and as an identity column. It is just not the default to mark the `byte` primary key as identity. But you can overwrite this default:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public byte Id { get; set; }
```

Setting the `Identity` option explicitly is not necessary for an `int`, a `long` and a `short` (and perhaps more types?), but it is for a `byte` (= `tinyint` in SQL Server). I figured it out by testing but couldn't find it officially documented anywhere.

Comment: For a `short` property which is a non-Identify Primary Key I had to use this attribute with the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` value.  Thanks!

Comment: Simply tacking on a new attribute with an additional Add-Migration did not work for me.  The IDENTITY(1,1) did not add.  I had to delete my migrations and the table before it finally added.  I'm using EF 6.1.3.