# EntityFramework 6.1 Add Method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very simple problem. Always use like this, but now not working, why i dont know.

I'm working on MVC 4 and Entity Framework 6.1. 
I have sql table like picture below which name is Kategori,

**Translation:** KategoriID -> *CategoryID*, KategoriIsmi -> *Category*, UstKategoriId -> *ParentCategoryID*

[image]

**KategoriID column has also, Primary Key and Identity Specification YES (Identity Increment 1, Seed 1)**

And this is my **Kategori** Model class

```
public class Kategori
{
    [Key]
    public byte? KategoriID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please insert category name")]
    public string KategoriIsmi { get; set; }
    public byte? UstKategoriID { get; set; }
}
```

And my save code with EntityFramework

```
public void AddNewItem(Kategori item)
{
        using (EmlakCMSContext _ent = new EmlakCMSContext())
        {
            _ent.Kategori.Add(item);
            _ent.SaveChanges();
        } 
}
```

When I run this code

Income data (for save in db)
[image]

I have a error. And I write code, watch the error in IntelliTrace.
[image]

**Error Translate:** KategoriID alanı gereklidir -> CategoryID field is required.

But KategoriID field have set auto increment true. 
How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell as the error message is not in English. However, your primary key should not use a nullable data type. Change this:

```
public byte? KategoriID { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public byte KategoriID { get; set; }
```

You may also need to tell entity framework that the column is an IDENTITY column:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public byte KategoriID { get; set; }
```

Comment: it translates to 'KategoriID field is required'

Comment: Change like you say, but now I have a error like this.`{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Kategori' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}`

Comment: that means you are setting the primary key manually (well EF is trying to) while the database expects it to be auto generated. If you want to enable IDENTITY_INSERT execute this SQL code: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] ON;`

Comment: See my edit, it seems EF isn't aware that the column is an identity column

Comment: I agree in most cases it is not recommended. Anyways if you want to use DB generated: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202203/using-byte-as-the-primary-key-datatype so use this attribute on your PK: `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: Hmm.. then howcome it's still not working? Did he forget that part?

Comment: @deherch I edited it in after (s)he posted the error in the comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58182/discussion-between-deherch-and-davidg).

Comment: Huge thank you DavidG :) My project with your last edit attribute `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`, perfectly working. Thank you :)