# System.InvalidCastException, Entity Framework with tinyint Identity column

Tags: entity-framework-6

When the following code runs

```
var op = context.Operation.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Operation1 == null);
```

I get an error

```
  System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Byte()
  InnerException:
```

I notice that EF 6.1.3 has mapped the column Operation to a name Operation1 because the table is also called Operation

The table structure has

```
[OperationID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Operation] [varchar](255) NULL
```

Comment: What is the smallest numeric integer type that can be used with EF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202203/using-byte-as-the-primary-key-datatype

Comment: I discovered that there was a join between a shortint in on table and a byte type,  in another table structure.  I am guessing this may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public byte EntidadeID { get; set; }
```